# Trigger an event when a thread is finished

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

Hi Python and Tkinter Gurus,
I am trying to build a simple GUI which has two buttons. When the Button is clicked, a thread is started to do some work. This work normally takes 10s/15s. And the GUI also works fine.

But I want to implement a pop-up to notify which thread has been completed. I have checked `t.isAlive()` function and could not implement it because I don't know how to trigger an event based on isAlive in the main loop.

Here is my sample code

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import Tkinter
import ttk

class SmallGui:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title('test gui')

        self.button_1 = ttk.Button(self.master,
                                   text='Start 1',
                                   command=lambda: self.init_thread(1))

        self.button_2 = ttk.Button(self.master,
                                   text='Start 2',
                                   command=lambda: self.init_thread(2))

        self.button_1.pack()
        self.button_2.pack()

    def init_thread(self, work):
        if work == 1:
            t = Thread(target=self.work_1)
            t.start()
        else:
            t = Thread(target=self.work_2)
            t.start()

    @staticmethod
    def work_1():
        print 'Work 1 started'
        # Do some Task and return a list
        sleep(10)

    @staticmethod
    def work_2():
        print 'Work 2 Started'
        # Do some Task and return a list
        sleep(15)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    run_gui = SmallGui(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why not add a popup message at the last line of the function that is being ran in the thread. You can use messagebox from tkinter here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use tkinter's messagebox. Tkinter has a built in method that can be used for all kinds of pop-up messages or questions. Here we will use `messagebox.showinfo`.

I am working on Python 3.X so I added a import method that will work for both 3.X and 2.X versions of python.

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

try:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import tkMessageBox as mb
    import ttk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import messagebox as mb
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class SmallGui:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title('test gui')

        self.button_1 = ttk.Button(self.master,
                                   text='Start 1',
                                   command=lambda: self.init_thread(1))

        self.button_2 = ttk.Button(self.master,
                                   text='Start 2',
                                   command=lambda: self.init_thread(2))

        self.button_1.pack()
        self.button_2.pack()

    def init_thread(self, work):
        if work == 1:
            t = Thread(target=self.work_1)
            t.start()
        else:
            t = Thread(target=self.work_2)
            t.start()

    @staticmethod
    def work_1():
        print ('Work 1 started')
        # Do some Task and return a list
        sleep(1)
        mb.showinfo("test", "Work 1 complete")

    @staticmethod
    def work_2():
        print ('Work 2 Started')
        # Do some Task and return a list
        sleep(1)
        mb.showinfo("test", "Work 2 complete")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    run_gui = SmallGui(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

UPDATE:

For whatever reason my above solution works in python 3 but no in 2.7.14.

The below example however does work in 2.7.14 and should work for you.

What I have done here is create 2 class attributes to monitor each thread.
I have created a method that will check ever 1 second if a thread is active and if the thread becomes inactive a messagebox will popup.

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox as mb
import ttk


class SmallGui(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.title('test gui')

        self.button_1 = ttk.Button(self.master,
                                   text='Start 1',
                                   command=lambda: self.init_thread(1))

        self.button_2 = ttk.Button(self.master,
                                   text='Start 2',
                                   command=lambda: self.init_thread(2))

        self.button_1.pack()
        self.button_2.pack()

        self.work1_status = None
        self.work2_status = None

    def init_thread(self, work):
        if work == 1:
            self.work1_status = Thread(target=self.work_1)
            self.work1_status.start()
            self.check_thread(self.work1_status, work)
        else:
            self.work2_status = Thread(target=self.work_2)
            self.work2_status.start()
            self.check_thread(self.work2_status, work)

    def check_thread(self, pass_thread, thread_name):
        if pass_thread.isAlive() == False:
                pass_thread = None
                mb.showinfo("test", "Work {} complete".format(thread_name))
        else:
            self.after(1000, lambda: self.check_thread(pass_thread, thread_name))

    @staticmethod
    def work_1():
        print ('Work 1 started')
        # Do some Task and return a list
        sleep(5)

    @staticmethod
    def work_2():
        print ('Work 2 Started')
        # Do some Task and return a list
        sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    run_gui = SmallGui(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I ran the code but the GUI becomes unresponsive once Start 1 button is clicked.

Comment: @daanav did you copy my code or did you update your own?

Comment: @daanav I am testing it now with 2.7 and it does seam to have an issues in 2.7. I do not know why as it works in python 3 without issue. I will keep looking into it.

Comment: Thanks. For your previous question, yes I had copied your code

Comment: @daanav Threading is a little difficult to work with sometimes in tkinter. That said I have come up with something that should work for you. Take a look at my 2nd example.